# What are zero terminated strings below vftable in RTTI?

Tags: disassembly, c++

I am reversing a class, which has RTTI information. It has 2 virtual functions in its vftable, and in IDA Pro I can see some kind of zero terminated strings below the last vfunction. Here's how it looks like:

```
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB598 ; class BSTValueEventSource<ViewCasterUpdateEvent>: BSTEventSink<BSTValueRequestEvent<ViewCasterUpdateEvent> >;   (#classinformer)
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB598                 dq offset ??_R4?$BSTValueEventSource@VViewCasterUpdateEvent@@@@6B@ ; const BSTValueEventSource<ViewCasterUpdateEvent>::`RTTI Complete Object Locator'
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB5A0 ; const BSTValueEventSource<class ViewCasterUpdateEvent>::`vftable'
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB5A0 ??_7?$BSTValueEventSource@VViewCasterUpdateEvent@@@@6B@ dq offset sub_7FF6ED1A39F0
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB5A0                                         ; DATA XREF: sub_7FF6ED19DC00:loc_7FF6ED19DC13↑o
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB5A0                                         ; sub_7FF6ED19E180:loc_7FF6ED19E263↑o ...
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB5A8                 dq offset sub_7FF6ED1A4560 ; //
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB5B0 aTtcastray      db 'TtCastRay',0        ; DATA XREF: sub_7FF6ED19E2D0+AF9↑o
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB5B0                                         ; sub_7FF6ED1A4F80+48↑o ...
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB5BA                 align 20h
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB5C0 aBusefuzzypicki db 'bUseFuzzyPicking:Interface',0
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB5C0                                         ; DATA XREF: .data:00007FF6EFF50D68↓o
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB5DB                 align 20h
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB5E0 aFactivatepickr db 'fActivatePickRadius:Interface',0
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB5E0                                         ; DATA XREF: .data:00007FF6EFF50D80↓o
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB5FE                 align 20h
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB600 aFactivatepickl db 'fActivatePickLength:Interface',0
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB600                                         ; DATA XREF: .data:00007FF6EFF50D98↓o
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB61E                 align 20h
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB620 aFlargeactivate db 'fLargeActivatePickLength_G:Interface',0
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB620                                         ; DATA XREF: .data:00007FF6EFF50DB0↓o
.rdata:00007FF6EF4FB645                 align 8
...
```

It seems that those strings can provide some useful information, but all the sources on RTTI I read didn't have anything that could explain them.

What could those strings be?

Comment: But they are cross-referenced, so IDA helpfully indicates they are used somewhere else. What do those XREF's point to?

Comment: @usr2564301 I don't know why I haven't checked the XREF's. One of the XREF's is referenced from a place related to a class SettingT<INISettingCollection>. So it seems those string have to do with the settings in INI, and are not related to RTTI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *usr2564301* suggested, I checked the XREF's provided by IDA. They pointed to a class `SettingT<INISettingCollection>`.

It looks like those string have nothing to do with RTTI and are related to settings in an INI file.